How to force UI draw in ElectronJS prior to intense computation task?
I am building an Electron program to identify molecular ions from precise mass determinations.  The calculation can take several seconds or even a few minutes.  To let the user know that it is processing, I would like to change the text on the button that starts the calculation to "Processing..." before the intense calculation begins.  But Everything I try results in the change being displayed after the calculation completes!
In principle I thought this would work, as a similar code works for reading the atomic mass database before parsing it.
function fnFindSCM(){

  async function showProcessing() {
    document.getElementById("btnFindSCM").innerHTML = "Processing...";   
  }

  async function awaitShowProcessing(){
    await showProcessing();

  }

  awaitShowProcessing();

  reallyFindSCM();

}

The function fnFindSCM() is the button's click event listener, while reallyFindSCM() is the function that does the heavy calculations.
I am hoping that a solution to this problem will also solve my next problem -- displaying "hits" as they are found rather than all at once when the search is complete.

Your async function showProcessing() needs to return a Promise in order for the timing to work as you would expect. Here's how I would restructure the code you provided:
function fnFindSCM() {
    async function showProcessing() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            document.getElementById("btnFindSCM").innerHTML = "Processing...";
            resolve();
        });
    }

    showProcessing()
        .then(() => {
            // Allow UI to update before calling the next function
            return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
        })
        .then(() => reallyFindSCM())
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}


Your code looks much nicer than mine, but results in the same performance.  The name on the button changes only after the heavy processing in reallyFindSCM() has finished.

I've updated my answer, see if that fixes the issue with UI not updating

Thank you!  This worked perfectly once I changed to return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10));
